# Group is kernel of some homomorphism direct product $G \cong \ker(f) \oplus H$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, direct-product

If $G,H$ are abelian groups, $f_1:G\to H$ and $f_2:H \to G$ are group homomorphisms such that $f_1f_2=\text{id}_H$, then  $G \cong \ker(f_1) \oplus H$

This question is HW from http://www.math.buffalo.edu/~badzioch/MTH619/Lecture_Notes_files/MTH619_week6.pdf (not my HW, but not sure if I can post this)

My attempt:

As $f_1 \circ f_2 = \text{id}_H$, $f_2$ is injective and $f_1$ is surjective. So all elements $H$ can be expressed as $f_1(g)$ for some $g \in G$ and $f_1(g_1)=f_1(g_2)$ implies $g_1=g_2$.

I tried the map $\pi:\ker(f_1) \oplus H \to G$ by $\pi (k,h) = kf_2(h)$. Then $f_1 \pi(k,h)=f_1(k)h=h$, and I was able to show injectivity. But I don’t know how to show surjectivity.

Injective:
\begin{align*}
\pi(k_1,h_1)=\pi(k_2,h_2) & \implies k_1f_2(h_1)=k_2f_2(h_2) \\
& \implies h_1=h_2 \text{ by applying $f_1$}\\
& \implies k_1=k_2 \text{ by cancellation on $f_2(h)$}
\end{align*}

Surjective: want $g=kh$ for all $g \in G$ for some $k \in \ker(f_1), h \in H$

Comment: Show that $k = g(f_2 \circ f_1)(g)^{-1}$ is in the kernel of $f_1$, then pick $h = f_1(g)$.

Comment: $f_1(g(f_2 \circ f_1)(g^{-1})) = f_1(g)f_1(g)^{-1}=1_H$ as function composition is associative, and $\pi(k,f_1(g))=g(f_2 \circ f_1)(g^{-1})(f_2 \circ f_1)(g) = g$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Rushy , your comment was as good as an answer, why not leave it as an answer instead of comment?